# Start Date and End Date not visible when using Content Query Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a Calendar List and I am querying it via Content Query Web Part, but when I try to filter based on Start and End Dates, I dont see these columns under Additional Filters.

Anyone has any idea how can solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried this before but my suggestion is to

Try filter based on Modified Date 1st , if it works then Start Date , End Date should also work